# Did Job hold the priesthood according to LDS teaching?

Tags: lds, priesthood, job

According to LDS teaching, did Job have the priesthood?

It would make sense for Job to be a high priest, since his life pointed towards Christ (which is a main duty of high priests), but I could find any sources talking about Job's priesthood.

Comment: according tothe LDS there isn't any doctrine stating if Job held the priesthood or not. He wasn't a prophet see: https://www.lds.org/ensign/2014/08/old-testament-prophets-job?lang=eng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Job lived during a time when a father was the priest for his family. Job 1:5 says,

> When a period of feasting had run its course, Job would make
>   arrangements for them to be purified. Early in the morning he would
>   sacrifice a burnt offering for each of them, thinking, “Perhaps my
>   children have sinned and cursed God in their hearts.” This was Job’s
>   regular custom.

At the end of the book, in Job 42, it says:

> 7 After the Lord had said these things to Job, he said to Eliphaz the
>   Temanite, “I am angry with you and your two friends, because you have
>   not spoken the truth about me, as my servant Job has. 8 So now take
>   seven bulls and seven rams and go to my servant Job and sacrifice a
>   burnt offering for yourselves. My servant Job will pray for you, and I
>   will accept his prayer and not deal with you according to your folly.
>   You have not spoken the truth about me, as my servant Job has.” 9 So
>   Eliphaz the Temanite, Bildad the Shuhite and Zophar the Naamathite did
>   what the Lord told them; and the Lord accepted Job’s prayer.
>
> 10 After Job had prayed for his friends, the Lord restored his
>   fortunes and gave him twice as much as he had before.

In this instance, Job is called upopn by God to act as a priest to accept sacrifices on behalf of his "friends". However, no mention is made of creating an enduring, hereditary priesthood as was the case with Aaron and Levi.

So I would say that Job was a priest.